# How do i check if a particular string is not present in a list in c#?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list as follows,

```
List<string> variablelist = new List<string> { "first", "second","third"};
```

And i have one more list, like

```
 List<string> method = new List<string>();
 //somecode
 method.Add(workingline);
```

I want to check if any of the element of `variablelist` is NOT present in `method`list and also I want get that Particular ELEMENT.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be another solution to it.

```
 var list = variablelist.Where(ItemName => !method.Contains(ItemName)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But suppose if my method list contains a line like `first = string.Empty;` and `first` element is already present in my variableList list but does not capture, since those are not exact match. can i match these elements like first element can be in any format in method list? –

Comment: i dont understand, could you explain it with an edit ?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 11):

LINQ is the simplest way of doing this, with the [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var inOnlyVariableList = variableList.Except(method).ToList();
```

The result will be a `List<string>` of strings which are in `variableList` but not in `method`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But suppose if my `method` list contains a line like ` first = string.Empty;` and `first` element is already present in my `variableList ` list but does not capture, since those are not exact match. can i match these elements like `first` element can be in any format in `method` list?

Comment: @Malai: If you wanted something other than string equality, you should have specified that in the question. I suggest you ask a *new* question with a [mcve] and a *precise* description of what you're looking for.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @Malai: No, you shouldn't do that. It's rude to update a question in a way that invalidates existing answers, when you asked a reasonably clear question to start with, but not the one you *wanted* to ask. Instead, you should ask a *new* question - please roll back your edit, and ask the new question separately.